# ~/bin no more in the PATH

Tags: bash, fish

I used to have a folder ~/bin with soft links to my local applications.

After the last installation, **fish shell** is no more adding this folder to the PATH.

Any explanation about why this stopped to work or why was it working before?

```
> lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

> fish -version
fish, version 3.0.2
```

UPDATE: I supposed that fish was using the bash config as well, but I was completely wrong and it makes sense. Two different shells, two different config files. In fact, bash scripts are not compatible with fish.

Comment: It works for me in the same version. But you must have such a directory for it to get into your PATH. Create it and reboot. Then it should be in your PATH.

Comment: Yes, I have the folder. In fact, it was working until execute "sudo apt full-upgrade" I updated it in the PATH manually, in the .bashrc. and it is working again. But this option was a default check in the .bashrc but now I can not find it in there.

Comment: Looks like is not reading the .profile

Comment: It looks like it is something related to fish shell and not with bash. But I don't understand why it happened. I did not touch anything and it was working before. Next time I need to pay attention to what it is updating.

Comment: I do not know the fish shell. Does it have its own rc-file?

Comment: Maybe set the PATH in ~/.config/fish/config.fish

Comment: Yes, fish has his own rc file. What I don't know is why before the update it was adding the ~/bin into the path and not now. Updating the question.

Comment: Here's a discussion about fish paths: https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/527